# Access dom after "chrome-document-global-created"

Tags: firefox, dom, firefox-addon, domcontentloaded

I need to get the DOM when the Mozilla observer event `"chrome-document-global-created"` is fired. Therefore, I have the following code. But how can I get the DOM from there? Data is `null` (according to documentation), can someone please tell me which object i have to use?

Many thanks!

```js
observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
  which object is it? document? window? cant find anything there about dom...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications#Documents), `subject` is a window. You still need to use [`QueryInterface()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsISupports#QueryInterface%28%29) to actually get the `nsIDOMWindow` interface but after that things get pretty obvious:

```js
var doc = subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow).document;
dump(doc.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

Note that there won't be much in the document at this point - it has just been created. As Boris Zbarsky notes in the comments, you probably want to add a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener to wait for the document contents to become available:

```js
var wnd = subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);
wnd.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event)
{
  dump(wnd.document.documentElement.innerHTML);
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, Wladimier!
But one further question: doc.documentElement.innerHTML just returns the "top-level" nodes (<head>, <body>). So i tried to get the content of the body via: doc.body.innerHTML but this seems to be empty. This is due to the event, meaning i cannot get the page's content via the "chrome-document-global-created"?

Comment: The global-created notification runs as soon as the Window object is created, before the document has been parsed.  If you want the full DOM, you should add a DOMContentLoading event handler at that point, I would think.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky: Thank you, forgot to note that - I adjusted the answer.

Comment: Ah okay. But i've noticed, that some extension (e.g. adblock plus) manipulate the dom before the DOMContentLoaded-Event was fired. How is this possible then? Nevertheless, the DOMSubstreeModified event gets fired before the DOMContentLoaded...

Comment: @FabianFrank: Adblock Plus doesn't manipulate the DOM. It prevents some loads via `nsIContentPolicy` and it installs a global stylesheet via `nsIStylesheetService`. In the end: you got an answer to the question you asked. You might want to ask a new question where you explain *what* you are trying to achieve, not *how* you are trying to achieve it. Maybe there are better solutions that you simply didn't think about.